# Optimization Problem with fast matrix-vector multiplication in Python / cvxpy

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, fft, cvxpy

I want to solve the following (convex) minimization problem:

min ||x||_1  under the constraints sgn(A[x,R]=y) and ||x||_2 = 1

where `A` is a mx(N+1) matrix, `x` in R^N a vector, and `\[x,R\]` a vector that is created by appending a given number `R`. The objective is to find the optimal value for `x`.

`A` is a Fourier matrix and there are fast matrix-vector, inversion, etc. algorithms available. Since this matrix is really big, I need to use an optimization algorithm that utilizes this.

Currently, I use the following implementation in cvxpy, which is way too slow:

```
import cvxpy as cvx

# rewrite the problem in the form x = x^- + x^+
n = A.shape[1]-1
vx = cvx.Variable(2*n)
objective = cvx.Minimize(cvx.pnorm(vx, 1)) # min ||x||_1
constraints = [vx >= 0, cvx.multiply(A[:,:n] @ vx[:n] - A[:,:n] @ vx[n:] + A[:,n]*R, y) >= 0,
               cvx.norm(vx, 2) <= R] # sgn(A[x,1]) = y, ||x||_2 <= R
x, solve_time = solve(vx, objective, constraints)
solution = x[:n] - x[n:]
```

Is there a way to use fast matrix computations in cvxpy? Or is there a better library? I found a few implementations that can do this for one special algorithm but not in the general case, so I was not able to implement my problem.

Comment: Looks very strange `sgn(A[x,R]=y)` . Certainly not usual notation.

Answer (score 1):

No. The solver will not call your matrix multiplication code. They do their own linear algebra, which is very different in many ways. In a sense your matrix multiplication is just notation for the problem statement.

Regarding performance, it depends heavily on where the bottleneck is. Is it in generating the model (in cvxpy itself) or in the solver? What solver are you using? Consider using a different solver. Obviously, we don't have enough information (and no reproducible example) to answer this question.